# Thought & Had thought

Tags: meaning, difference

What is the difference in meaning between ...

> "I saw him again last year, I thought he was tall"

and

> "I saw him again last year, I had thought he was tall"

Comment: There must be a duplicate on [ELL.SE] to [remove the migration and] link to.

Answer (score 1):

When you say:

> I saw him again last year, *and* I **thought** he was tall.

This is just a statement of something that happened in the past.

> I saw him again last year, *and* I **had thought** he was tall.

by itself seems incomplete, as it implies that your opinion changed at a later date. You could write:

> I saw him again last year, *and* I had thought he was tall. But when I saw him last week, I noticed that he was not that tall. I suppose I had stars in my eyes.

I added *and* because you need a conjunction when joining independent clauses with a comma. Your wording is OK if you use a semi-colon:

> I saw him again last year; I **thought** he was tall.

but with short clauses I would use a comma instead.

Comment: Agree with your point of view on past perfect

Answer (score 0):

The use of "thought" implies you used to think he is tall, but you do not anymore. Perhaps something changed your mind in the conversation.

The use of "had thought" also implies you used to think he is tall, but you changed your mind long before the conversation that is happening.

The use of "think" shows that at the moment of converstion, you believe he is tall, perhaps based on your observation last year.

To conclude, "thought" and "had thought" both indicate a change of mind, the difference is when the change happens, at the moment of conversation or earlier.