# Which one is correct? I thought or I had thought

Tags: grammar

Imagine someone needed a water but I brought him tea by mistake.

He say: I didn't want to drink tea.
I say : sorry I **thought** you wanted to drink tea.
Or
Sorry I **had thought** you wanted to drink tea.

Also I'm completely confused about how to use verbs after 'thought'
I thought you **wanted**
Or
I thought you **want**

Comment: Minor corrections: "Imagine someone needed **some** water, but I brought him tea by mistake. He **said**, "I didn't want tea". I **said**, "Sorry I thought you wanted tea".  This is perfectly fine. You don't need to use "I had thought" here. It's perfectly fine to use the simple past tense here.

Comment: As ever, if you don't *need* the perfect form (which you *certainly* don't here) you should avoid it. But note that we nearly always "backshift" after "I thought..." even if the thing you thought ***was and is still true***. So if you're surprised when you see your friend light a cigarette, you say *I thought you **didn't** smoke* rather than *I thought you **don't** smoke*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thought & Had thought](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70154/thought-had-thought)

Comment: I thought you had wanted tea but now I realise I was wrong . Do I need to use perfect in this case?

Comment: @YvesLefol - No, you don't.

Comment: Thanks all.I got it