# Why is the first example past perfect as both examples have the same meaning?

Tags: past-tense

Could you cancel my first order, please? Since I thought my order **hadn't gone** through the first time, I tried again. However, I now realize it did work the first time. In other words, I accidentally ordered the same item twice

Imagine someone needed a glass of water but I brought him a glass of tea by mistake.

He said: I didn't want to drink tea.

I replied : sorry I thought you **wanted** to drink tea but now I realise I was wrong .

I don't understand why the first one is not past simple " did not get through". The meaning is in both sentences:" I thought something happened  or did not happen and in fact I realise I was wrong"  . Both actions are almost simultaneous and in chronological order :

The payment,the  thinking of the non  payment and in fact perhaps the payment

Client wants water,the thinking of  tea  for the client  and the mistake (I realise he did not want tea )

Comment: Is [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/338859/which-one-is-correct-i-thought-or-i-had-thought) your question too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order 'going through' is a single action which either has or has not happened.

The person wanting either tea or water is an ongoing situation. You could say to him "I thought you *had asked for* a cup of tea" (a single action).

Comment: I think I don't see the difference in the second example when the waiter brought a cup of tea, the customer still wanted a glass  of water so it is also an ongoing situation . In the first  case we can not used past perfect because the verb is want  and the desire  to drink is still here even if it is not the right beverage

Comment: That's what I said - the fact that the customer wanted a particular drink is an ongoing situation. But _asking for_ tea or water is an action which is in the past by the time the waiter brings the wrong drink.